# Django: Attributes not being applied to some fields in custom form

Tags: django

I have a custom form to register a user in my Django application. This custom form is inherited from the django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm class. In  my custom form class, I want to add custom HTML attributes to the fields. When I do this, attributes are added to only some fields and not others. In my case, the custom attribute 'class' is added only to the 'email' field and not 'username' field. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong here and help me solve the problem.

The code for my custom form is here:

```
class EmployeeRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
        widgets = {'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'username'}),
                    'email':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'email'})}
```

Comment: tip: you can remove `model = User` if change `class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):`

Comment: regarding the issue, seems everything good (except pep spaces) with this code, check, maybe further, somewhere in stack calls - `username` widget is overridden