# Django: Attributes Not Being Applied to Form

Tags: django, django-forms

As the title states I have a django form that I am trying to customize yet for some reason the attributes are not being applied to it. I have used the exact same code in other projects and it worked perfectly except now for some reason it is not. The only other question I have found by googling is this one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075888/django-attributes-not-being-applied-to-some-fields-in-custom-form). I have the exact same issue as this, I am trying to inject attributes into my label field but for what ever reason it is not working no matter what I have tried. My code is as follows:

```
class MyAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['username'].widget = forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
        self.fields['password'].widget = forms.widgets.PasswordInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
```

The weirdest thing was when I first started coding this morning it worked, then every subsequent time I visited my form it stopped. I truly have no idea what is going on and why this isn't working. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block css_files  %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'login-out.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  {% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
      please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}
      <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}

  <section id="form-test">
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.username.label_tag }}
            {{ form.username }}
            {{ form.password.label_tag }}
            {{ form.password }}
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
          </div>
        <input class='btn btn-outline-primary' type="submit" value="Login" />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    </form>
  
    
    <p><a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Lost password?</a></p>
  </section>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Show your template...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Added!